# Element not being located in Angular app when using XPath as Locator

Tags: angular, xpath, protractor

I am trying to write a Protractor test that uses the XPath to click an `<a>` tag that's part of my Angular app.

Below is what I currently have:

```
it('should click the Calculators menu button', () => {
    var listItem2 = element(by.xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-shell/app-menu/div[2]/ul/li[3]'));
    listItem2.click().then(() => {
        browser.sleep(10000);
    });
});
```

When I run  the test, I get this error message:

> Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath, /html/body/app-root/app-shell/app-menu/nav/div[2]/ul/li[3])

When I inspect the `<a>` tag & click `Copy full XPath`, the XPath above is the value that I'm getting.

I have a feeling the issue is around `frames`. For example, when I enter my login credentials & click Login, I'm brought to a different URL.

Can someone please tell me why this XPath isn't being recognised.

Here is the HTML in the console:

[image: HTML_in_console]

Comment: what happens when you try this xpath in browser console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add an [expected condition](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable) before the click. Something like :

```
var elm = element(by.xpath('//ul[@class="nav navbar-nav pull-right navigation"]/li[3]/a'));
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elm), 5000);
elm.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss a `nav` tag:

```
 /html/body/app-root/app-shell/app-menu/nav/div[2]/ul/li[3]
```

But better do:

```
//app-root/app-shell/app-menu/nav/div/ul/li[3]/a
```

Comment: Thanks for your message, but I've tried both of these & the error message is still saying element not found

Comment: Can you share a link or a copy of the HTML ?

Comment: Maybe you have an issue with the code around, I dunno Angular at all